# Slide Up Menu for iPhone app

Tags: xcode

I have a slide up menu in my app that opens when a button is pushed. The problem is when I turn on my app the menu is already open. How do I have the menu closed until the button is pushed?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! In inspector view I didn't have my size of the `UITextView` correct.